# How add a back button manually in NavigationPage?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a login page in Xamarin.Forms without `NavigationPage`, but I have a button in this page to navigate to other page to create a new user and, in the page of insert user, I need add a back button to allow users go back to the login page.

How can I do that?

ps: I'm using Prism framework.

My code to open login page:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("Login", parametrosNavegacao);
```

My code to navigate to page that register user:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/CadastroUsuario", useModalNavigation: true);
```

Comment: So, I guess you don't just push the Register page to the navigation stack on top of the login page?

Comment: Not super fimilar with Prism, but it looks like you're using a modal page. Any reason to not add a Cancel toolbar item to the insert user page? It will be right aligned though. If you need a left aligned back button, there are some blog posts where people have implemented that, like [this](https://timeyoutake.it/2016/01/02/creating-a-left-toolbaritem-in-xamarin-forms/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
NavigationService.PopupGoBackAsync();
```

https://github.com/dansiegel/Prism.Plugin.Popups

Comment: While this may help him with the actual stack navigation, it doesn't answer his actual question of how to add a back button to the view.

Comment: He said he already have a button, so I assume he knows how to create one. He is just missing answer on how to navigate back.

Comment: No, I didn't say that I have a button. That is the problem: the back button doesn't appear in my page, because previous page doesn't have a NavigationPage.

Answer (score 0):

One option can be

```
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/Login");
```

the / bebore Login means Absolute url, and prism clears navigation stack, other wise clicking android's back button will again open up insert user page.

Comment: That is not my problem. I don't have the back button on my Navigation Bar, than I can't back